# Fujitsu Primergy RX100 S7, e1000e driver, cannot establish link

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, drivers

We have a Fujitsu Primergy RX100 S7 server. It has two Gigabit Ethernet ports: Intel 82574L Gigabit Ethernet, Intel 82579LM Gigabit Ethernet. Cards use e1000e driver. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the server. Both network cards fail to connect to (different) ethernet switches reporting there is no carrier.

Is there a known issue? Any workaround?

**Updated**:

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.1 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C202 Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Graphics, Inc. MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1) (rev 05)
```

Also, don't know why, second ethernet port (eth1) is detecting link. So only one of those ports can't see carrier. lshw:

```
second                
    description: Rack Mount Chassis
    product: PRIMERGY RX100 S7 (ABN:K1385-V201-24)
    vendor: FUJITSU
    version: GS05
    serial: YLAP014393
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=rackmount family=SERVER sku=ABN:K1385-V201-24 uuid=C0CD0617-7F24-11E1-A334-2B3D2BBF72F6
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: D3034-A1
       vendor: FUJITSU
       physical id: 0
       version: S26361-D3034-A100 WGS01 GS03
       serial: LJ3A-P01950
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: FUJITSU // American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: V4.6.4.1 R1.21.0 for D3034-A1x
          date: 03/16/2012
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal varies
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 5
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 6
          size: 8MiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 24
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber0
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: A1_SerNum0
             slot: DIMM-2A
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M391B5273DH0-YK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 3357D4F4
             slot: DIMM-1A
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber2
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer2
             physical id: 2
             serial: A1_SerNum2
             slot: DIMM-2B
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M391B5273DH0-YK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 3
             serial: 3357D24B
             slot: DIMM-1B
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 3e
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei latency=0
             resources: irq:49 memory:fba26000-fba2600f
        *-communication:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.1
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fba25000-fba2500f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eth0
             version: 04
             serial: 00:22:4d:67:d3:52
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.5.1-k firmware=0.13-4 ip=195.158.12.79 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:45 memory:fba00000-fba1ffff memory:fba24000-fba24fff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:fba23000-fba233ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fb900000-fb9fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth1
                version: 00
                serial: 00:22:4d:67:d3:51
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.5.1-k duplex=full firmware=2.1-0 ip=192.168.5.236 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:18 memory:fb900000-fb91ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:fb920000-fb923fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.7
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 memory:fa000000-fb8fffff
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1)
                vendor: Matrox Graphics, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 05
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:fb800000-fb803fff memory:fb000000-fb7fffff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:fba22000-fba223ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: C202 Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi1
             logical name: scsi4
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:44 ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:fba21000-fba217ff
           *-disk:0
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD5003ABYX-5
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 01.0
                serial: WD-WMAYP3337465
                size: 465GiB (500GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00000e30
              *-volume
                   description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   capacity: 465GiB
                   capabilities: primary multi
           *-disk:1
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD5003ABYX-5
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                version: 01.0
                serial: WD-WMAYP3301496
                size: 465GiB (500GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00051613
              *-volume
                   description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sdb1
                   capacity: 465GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable multi
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: DVD RW AD-7760H
                vendor: Optiarc
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/dvdrw
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: 1.41
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fba20000-fba200ff ioport:f000(size=32)
```

dmesg|egrep -e 'eth|e1000'

```
[    0.563797] i2c-core: driver [aat2870] using legacy suspend method
[    0.563799] i2c-core: driver [aat2870] using legacy resume method
[    1.364353] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 1.5.1-k
[    1.364358] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2011 Intel Corporation.
[    1.364388] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
[    1.364398] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.364486] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.669276] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:22:4d:67:d3:52
[    1.669281] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.669332] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: 313130-031
[    1.669342] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Disabling ASPM L0s 
[    1.669356] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    1.669379] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.669612] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.669616] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.669619] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.775587] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:22:4d:67:d3:51
[    1.775592] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.775678] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 313130-033
[    4.856622] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    4.856627] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[    5.244134] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[    5.387671] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.443255] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.443706] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.871987] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[    6.871991] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[    6.872558] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[   17.480573] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
[  148.624087] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Down
[  226.515981] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[  226.515987] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh. I have mixed up management interface and server interface. One of the server interfaces and management interface are located together. Second server interface is located much further to the right. So I was plugging cable into management link and expecting server interface to come up. My bad. Sigh. :-(

Comment: Hopefully if someone will make same mistake they fill find this post...

Answer (score 3):

Check that the cables are plugged in, that you get link light, and that the ports are enabled on the switches.  The `e1000e` driver is very reliable, and typically won't load if the NIC isn't supported by the driver, so the problem is going to almost certainly be a hardware one, not a driver problem.

Comment: I am absolutely positively sure that cables are plugged in.. :) Ports are enabled on the switches, we have tried even dumb unmanaged switches. Yes, this is also a first time I see problems with Intel network cards.

Answer (score 1):

Does `ethtool` show that a link is detected?

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: uag
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

That's checking as close to the physical layer as possible.

Comment: Yes, ethtool on eth1 is showing link. On eth0 ethtool reports speed and duplex as unknown and 'link detected' as 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs about signs of trouble - /var/log/syslog, /var/log/kern.log are good starters.

Make sure the e1000e module is loaded by `lsmod | grep e1000e`, then reload it `modprobe -r e1000e && modprobe e1000e`.

Finally, since you have no network probably your server is unusable. In this case, reboot to Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD and check if the network is operational.

These should give you a clue of what is wrong.

Comment: added output of dmesg. I don't see anything problematic there.